# JavaFX: How to refer to another object with the same fxml file?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I have got an `FXML` file in which there is a custom component declared. This component has some logic that requires a reference to another component declared in the same fxml file. The FXML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" prefWidth="800" prefHeight="400"  fx:controller="test.MyController">
    <top>
        <HBox spacing="10">
            <Label text="Test"/>
            <TextField fx:id="testField"/>
        </HBox>
    </top>
    <center>
        <AnchorPane>
            <children>
                <VBox fx:id="customBox" visible="false" prefHeight="400" prefWidth="400"
                                   VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"
                                   initiator="#testField"/>
            </children>
        </AnchorPane>
    </center>

</BorderPane>
```

So, I need to set the `initiator` property of `customBox`. With this, I am getting `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to coerce #testField to class javafx.scene.control.TextField.` Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You may set the id of textField (say `id="testFieldId"` which is different from `fx:id`) into `initiator` and do lookup:

```
// in VBox #customBox
TextField tf = (TextField) getScene().lookup(getInitiator());
```

where `getInitiator()` returns `String` = "#testFieldId".

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to test this, but I think

```
<KontrollkoderVBox fx:id="customBox" visible="false" prefHeight="400" prefWidth="400"
    VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"
    initiator="$testField"/>
```

will work. See ["variable resolution"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#variable_resolution) in the FXML documentation.

You can even do things like binding a `StringProperty` in `KontrolkoderVBox` to the `TextField`'s `textProperty()` by referencing `${testField.text}`.